# How to invoke methods after the user has successfully logged in?

Tags: jsf

Using container managed security on Glassfish, how can you make individual "profile" pages and restrict that only the person logged in is capable of changing it? Let say you have user "John" and "Amanda" and they both have the role "user", how can you be sure that only "John" can change his profile page, and not "Amanda"?

```
<form method="POST" action="j_security_check">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="j_username" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="j_password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Not sure why you posted the login jsp. Make sure the user id of the current user matches the user id of the profile being changed.

Comment: It is not JSP, it is JSF 2.0 --> XHTML. And where/how would you check this before the page is being accessed?

Comment: Profile page should be the same for all users, in meaning of composition and acessibility. Content will differ depending on user data fetched from DB. "John" can't simply change "Amandas" profile because first of all they work in different sessions and second, you store the data based on unique ID, so if  "John" makes any changes to his profile, only his "row" in DB will get updated. Restricting the access means you just put your profile page under the restricted pages accessible only to logged users with role "user". Check eg. [glassfish security](http://tinyurl.com/c4pmfcx)

Comment: Oh, true. @Fallup Can you come on Java chat?

Comment: @Viper Whatever; it's totally irrelevant to the question. The same way you do anything else--if you're retrieving, say, a product by id, you check if the ID exists, right? So if you're pulling up a profile page, you check if the profile you're pulling up belongs to the user. Or as Fallup says, just make the profile page load only the logged-in user's information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you check if the logged in user from the session and the profile you are asked to fetch from database are the same? If they don't match, the user cannot edit that page. Ideally, I would put this kind of user session logic in a server filter do that it can work on all requests.

Answer (score 1):

This could be easily done with SEAM Framework. You just create secured interface @Admin, then create a checker method public @Secure @Admin checkAdmin(Identity identity) {}

After that you can just add @Admin to your methods.

the other thing you can do, which is easier:
just use the attribute "rendered" and check which user is logged in.